# Should my kernel keep dying while one hot encoding this DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

Here are the details of the dataframe:

- Shape = (4584, 562)
- Number of Categorical Variables = 58

My computer has the following specs:

- 16GB of RAM
- 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7

Here is how I have written my code:

```
df_encoded = df

for idx, var in enumerate(cat_vars):
    temp = pd.get_dummies(df_encoded.iloc[:,idx], prefix = cat_vars[idx])

    temp = df_encoded.drop(cat_vars[0], axis=1)
    df_encoded = pd.concat([df_encoded, temp], axis=1)

df_encoded.head()
```

`cat_vars` are all of the features that have deemed categorical. Let me know if you'd like more information. This seems really odd that my computer isn't able to run this.

Answer (score 2):

I think loop is not necessary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('absdektg'),
                   'B':list('scfvbngf'),
                   'C':list('dsxcdscv'),
                   'D':list('fscvdcvf'),
                   'E':list('dswxaxcc')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  s  d  f  d
1  b  c  s  s  s
2  s  f  x  c  w
3  d  v  c  v  x
4  e  b  d  d  a
5  k  n  s  c  x
6  t  g  c  v  c
7  g  f  v  f  c

cat_vars = list('ABCD')
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[cat_vars])
df_encoded = pd.concat([df, df_encoded], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df_encoded)
   A  B  C  D  E  A_a  A_b  A_d  A_e  A_g ...   C_c  C_d  C_s  C_v  C_x  D_c  \
0  a  s  d  f  d    1    0    0    0    0 ...     0    1    0    0    0    0   
1  b  c  s  s  s    0    1    0    0    0 ...     0    0    1    0    0    0   
2  s  f  x  c  w    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    0    0    1    1   
3  d  v  c  v  x    0    0    1    0    0 ...     1    0    0    0    0    0   
4  e  b  d  d  a    0    0    0    1    0 ...     0    1    0    0    0    0   
5  k  n  s  c  x    0    0    0    0    0 ...     0    0    1    0    0    1   
6  t  g  c  v  c    0    0    0    0    0 ...     1    0    0    0    0    0   
7  g  f  v  f  c    0    0    0    0    1 ...     0    0    0    1    0    0   

   D_d  D_f  D_s  D_v  
0    0    1    0    0  
1    0    0    1    0  
2    0    0    0    0  
3    0    0    0    1  
4    1    0    0    0  
5    0    0    0    0  
6    0    0    0    1  
7    0    1    0    0  

[8 rows x 30 columns]
```

If need unique columns names add prameters `prefix` and `prefix_sep` and groupby by columns with aggregate `max`:

```
df_encoded1 = (pd.get_dummies(df[cat_vars], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
                .groupby(level=0, axis=1).max())
df_encoded1 = pd.concat([df, df_encoded1], axis=1)
print (df_encoded1)
   A  B  C  D  E  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  k  n  s  t  v  x
0  a  s  d  f  d  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
1  b  c  s  s  s  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
2  s  f  x  c  w  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
3  d  v  c  v  x  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
4  e  b  d  d  a  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  k  n  s  c  x  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0
6  t  g  c  v  c  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0
7  g  f  v  f  c  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: It actually ended up being more simple than that. See my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

As @jezrael stated, the for loop was not needed.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
df_encoded = df
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df_encoded, columns=cat_vars, sparse=True)
```

Comment: It seems you got something from his answer. So why no upvote?